# CMake (3.5.2) used non-absolute boost lib paths, doesn't -L my boost dir

Tags: c++, boost, linker, cmake

I have a system with a default version of Boost installed, and I have another version installed under `/opt`. I use:

```
find_package(Boost 1.54.0 QUIET REQUIRED
    COMPONENTS
    system program_options regex filesystem
)
```

That gives me `/opt/etc/etc/include` and `/opt/etc/etc/lib` in `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}` and `${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}`.

I also use:

```
target_link_libraries(tester
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${CUDA_LIBRARIES}
    ${CUDA_cupti_LIBRARY}
    nvToolsExt
    OpenCL
    cudadevrt
    # more stuff here
)
```

<sub>(this is not CUDA-linked code in case you're wondering)</sub>

As the Makefile executes, I see the compilation commands have `-I/opt/etc/etc/include`.

However, the link command doesn't use absolute names for boost libraries, and doesn't `-L/opt/etc/etc/boost` - while for other libraries (the CUDA ones), it does at least `-L` the appropriate directory.

So what happens is that the linker tries to use my system's default version of the boost libs. In other words, the linking command looks like:

```
g++ -bunch -of -switches bunch.o of.o files.o -lboost_system
-lboost_program_options -lboost_regex -lboost_filesystem -Wl,-Bstatic
-lcudart_static -Wl,-Bdynamic -lpthread -ldl -lrt 
/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64/libcupti.so -lnvToolsExt -lOpenCL
-lcudadevrt lib/morestuff.a -Wl,-Bstatic -lcudart_static -Wl,-Bdynamic
-lpthread -ldl -lrt -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
```

<sub>(Yes, there's redundancy, but that's not the issue here.)</sub>

Why might this be happening?

PS: I know this isn't quite an MCVE, so I'm asking for "common remedies" for such an issue.

---

**Edit:** I've tried switching my target_link_libraries command to:

```
target_link_libraries(tester
    Boost::system  Boost::program_options
    Boost::regex Boost::file_system
    ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} ${CUDA_cupti_LIBRARY} 
    nvToolsExt OpenCL cudadevrt ktkernels )
```

i.e. using imported targets. But I get:

```
Target "tester" links to target "Boost::file_system" but the target was not found
```

Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?

Comment: What is the content of `Boost_LIBRARIES`?

Comment: @wasthishelpful: it's `/opt/etc/etc/lib/libboost_system.so;/opt/etc/etc/lib/libboost_program_options.so;/opt/etc/etc/lib/libboost_regex.so;/opt/etc/etc/lib/libboost_filesystem.so`

Comment: That doesn't look coherent with your linking command. Did you try to use imported targets? Something like `target_link_libraries(tester Boost::system ...)`. If you want to go further your workaround, I am curious to see your complete CMake file

Comment: @wasthishelpful: I've not heard about imported targets before, but I will try it. ... Ok, tried it, it failed, see edit.

Comment: Weird. Can you please clean the cache, rerun cmake, and post the log (if it's too long, only the messages related to Boost will be enough) with your complete CMake (or at least a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))?

Comment: @wasthishelpful: I'll try generating an MCVE; it'll take a while though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This (workaround?) works:

```
set (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} "-L${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} "-L${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
```

in the CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: `link_directories("${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")` should be equivalent, but you should not have to use it

Comment: @wasthishelpful: Nope. It's not equivalent, unfortunately. With my workaround, the linkage command has it's `-L/opt/etc/etc/lib`; with your `link_directories` command - it doesn't (but it does have some more whitespace where I would expect the `-L` though).